# Why the Android back button not working when react-native-paper Dialog is visible?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-paper

I use `react-native-paper` non-dismissable `Dialog` component, and react navigation V5 for navigation, for some reason when the dialog is visible then the Android back button is not working and I have to close the Dialog to go back.

I tried to also use `BackHandler.addEventListener` but my handler is not being called at all.

How can I solve it?

**EDIT**: changed 'now' in title to 'not'

Comment: Upvoted this question! Did you found any solution to this?